# Show that a dynamical system is not ergodic (finding the invariant sets)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Given $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ a probability space. Consider the iid sequence of random variables $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ :
$$X_n \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,1).$$
Let $B:(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)\to \{\hbox{head},\hbox{tail}\}$ be a Bernoulli random variable: $B \sim \hbox{Bernoulli}(p)$. Define $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ as follows. Flip a coin according to $B$ and:

1. If it is head, set $Y_n=X_n$, for all $n$;
2. If it is tail, set $Y_n=0$, for all $n$.

Notice that $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is defined on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ with trajectories in $(\mathbb R^\mathbb N, \mathcal B^\mathbb N, P_Y)$, where $P_Y$ is the [law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_(stochastic_processes)) of the stochastic process $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$. Moreover, it is straightforwar to show that $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is stricty stationary.

According to Chapter V, [Probability](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Probability.html?id=r0zUBwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y), Albert Shiryaev, $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ generates a dynamical system $(T, P_Y)$ as follows. First, define $T: \mathbb R^\mathbb N \to \mathbb R^\mathbb N $ as:
$$T(x_1,x_2,...)= (x_2,x_3,...).$$
Since $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is stricty stationary, we have that $P_Y$ is $T$-invariant in the following sense:
$$P_Y(A)=P_Y(T^{-1}(A)), \quad \forall \, A \in \mathcal{B}^\mathbb N$$

We say that $(T, P_Y)$ is ergodic if:
$$P_Y(A)\in \{0,1\}, \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{I}_T$$
where $\mathcal{I}_T$ is the class of $T-$invariant sets (indeed, a $\sigma-$algebra), defined as :
$$\mathcal{I}_T:=\{A \in \mathcal B^\mathbb N : A = T^{-1}(A)\}$$

I **want to show** that $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is not ergodic. For this, I want to:

1. Find $\mathcal{I}_T$ for the dynamical system generated by $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$;
2. Show that $P_Y(A)\notin \{0,1\}$ for some $A \in \mathcal{I}_T$.

Your help in these **two points** can help me to show non-ergodicity in other more complex cases.

**Update question**

I am indeed interested in these two points above, but I would like to focus on showing whether it is true that $\mathcal{I}_T \subset \mathcal B^\mathbb N$ is related (in some sense) to  $\sigma(B) \subset \mathcal F$. Here, $\sigma(B)$ is the sigma algebra generated by the Bernoulli $B$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are what my considerations about it. To show that the dynamical system generated by $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is not ergodic, you can try to find a set $A \in \mathcal{I}_T$ such that $P_Y(A)\notin \{0,1\}$. One way to do this is to consider the set $A = \{(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N} : x_1 = 0\}$. Since $T(x_1,x_2,...)= (x_2,x_3,...)$, we have that $T^{-1}(A) = A$, so $A$ is a T-invariant set. Now we need to compute the probability of this set.

Since the coin flip determines whether all the $Y_n$ are equal to 0 or equal to the corresponding $X_n$, we have that
$$P_Y(A) = P(B=\text{tail}) = 1-p.$$
Thus, if $0 < p < 1$, then we have found a T-invariant set with probability strictly between 0 and 1, which shows that the dynamical system generated by $(Y_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is not ergodic.

Comment: A question: I don't see how $T^{-1}(A)=A$. We have $T^{-1}(A)=\{x:T(x)\in A\}=\{x:(x_2,x_3,...)=(0,x_3,...)\}$ but this is not $A$. Or is it?

Comment: I'm actually interested in knowing exactly who $\mathcal{I}_T$ is? I edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell now. $\mathcal{I}_T$ = {∅, A, B, ℝ^ℕ}, where A = {(x_1, x_2, ...) ∈ ℝ^ℕ : x_1 = 0} and B = {(x_1, x_2, ...) ∈ ℝ^ℕ : x_1 ≠ 0}